# WYSIWYG - как сделать подобное для web?

Tags: wysiwyg, веб-программирование, html

Есть необходимость сделать web-редактор WYSIWYG с небольшим набором функций (bold, italic, smiles и т.д.). Готовые варианты слишком навороченные, а вырезать из них код - не вариант.

Нужно сделать самому.

Например, нашел статью: [Правильный WYSIWYG](http://xpoint.ru/know-how/WYSIWYG/TrueJavaScriptEditor?comments). Но, насколько я понимаю, там описывается устаревший метод (через iFrame). Есть какие-то аналоги? И вообще каков принцип работы? (Слышал, что есть еще такой вариант: поверх обычного textarea (прозрачный) ставится слой (например, div), в котором отображается уже отформатированный текст; ну и способ с iFrame). Кто что может подсказать? Может ссылки есть полезные?

Comment: Используйте CKEditor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Нужно сделать самому.

```
iframe.designMode = 'On';
```

Готово!

И все визивиги строятся именно на этом принципе, поэтому и используют iframe, других вариантов нет и быть не может! DesignMode распространяется на весь документ, к которому применяется. Для ие точно не помню, как он звучит.

Самый лучший вариант сделать минимальный визивиг - это openWysiwyg; это open-source проект, выкинуть лишнее не составит труда, да и лишнего там особо ничего нет :)

Comment: Я так понимаю, DesignMode - это готовая реализация, но с ограниченным набором функций. Посмотреть к примеру WYSIWYG у В Контакте - у них нестандартные решения (к примеру - вставка таблиц), которые, как мне кажется, нельзя реализовать стандартными способами, встроенными в WYSIWYG? Или все же есть возможность использовать свою комбинацию тегов?

Answer (score 1):

iframe можно и не использовать, хотя так все же чаще поступают. Ключевым моментом в реализации редактирования типа WYSIWYG является свойство designMode у объекта document и свойство contentEditable у (почти) любого другого элемента, например, div'а. Фишка ведь в том, что лично вам не нужно создавать с нуля весь механизм редактирования непосредственно разметки (rich-text editing) - это уже реализовано в браузере. Хотя, конечно, чтобы создать полноценный WYSIWYG-редактор, нужно приложить еще много усилий.
Из того, что у меня есть в закладках на этот счет и еще работает:

- [Rich-Text Editing in Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla)
- [execCommand compatibility](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand.html)

Было еще несколько статей на fastcoder.ru, но он уже закрыт.

Comment: contentEditable - это HTML5 и о нем можно забыть, либо забыть об ie :)

Comment: Вот я не поленился перезагрузиться в винду и проверить в IE7 - contentEditable работает.
И кстати, вы можете смеяться, но designMode впервые ввели именно Microsoft.